# Thymeleaf - Setting Object's Field To Another Object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. I am making an E-Commerce application and I have a product class and a CartItems class.

The CartItems class contains a product in it, because in a cart you will have products inside and the CartItems basically takes the product you select and gets details like total price and quantity.

CartItems:

```
@Table(name = "cartitems")
public class CartItems implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "price")
private double price;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
private Cart cart;

public CartItems() {

}

public CartItems(Product product, int quantity, double price, Cart cart) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.product = product;
    this.cart = cart;
}
```

Catalog Thymeleaf Page:

```
 <div th:each="product : ${popularProducts}">
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/cart/'}" th:object="${cartItem}" method="POST">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" th:src="${product.pictureUrl}">
      <a href="#" class="card-link text-danger like">
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title" th:text="${product.getName()}"></h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"  th:text="${product.getCategory()}"></h6>
      <p class="card-text" th:text="${product.getDescription()}">
      <div class="buy d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="price text-success"><h5 class="mt-4" th:text="'$' + ${product.getPrice()}"></h5></div>
        <div class="form-group blu-margin">
         <div class="form-label-group">
              <input th:field="*{cartItem.quantity}" type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="1" required="required">
           </div>
        </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mt-3"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
```

The problem is with setting the CartItems.product equal to the currently displayed product.

I am looping through each product, and if the user presses Add To Cart, I want the **CartItem's product field to be equal to the currently displayed product**. How do you manually set this when you pass it back up the controller?

Is there a way of just typing ${cartItem.product = product} without having the user to manually write it as an input?

Alternatively, is there a way I can feed up the **product** : ${popularProducts}
using model attribute? How do I bring that up once the form is submitted along with CartItem object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by putting the product id into the post mapping address as a path variable then using the product repository to find the product by the id passed through then setting it manually in the controller.